# Rich text in an auto populated field in Adobe Acrobat

Tags: adobe-acrobat, rtf

I have a text field that has RTF to centre the multi-lines. This is retained with a space. As soon as i set it to populate from a hidden data field the Rich Text Formatting disappears. Any ideas how I keep rich text formating in an auto populated field?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to have a close look at the richValue Field Object property in the Acrobat JavaScript documentation, and you will have to do some processing to get your value into the richText field. It may be a little bit overwhelming to begin, but it is quite straightforward, but just a bit tedious work.

Hint: richValue is not a string; it is an Object…